# How to build the regex to find particular word

Tags: java, regex

I need to find and print out a particular word in a String. What regex can you recommend me to find a "9.1.1_offline" in following String:

EGA_SAMPLE_APP-iOS-master-**<Any word>**-200710140849862

Another examples are:

- EGA_SAMPLE_APP-iOS-master-**9.2.3_online**-200710140849862
- EGA_SAMPLE_APP-iOS-master-**10.2.3_offline**-200710140849862

Comment: See [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236). Also, [Do we need a close reason for zero-effort questions?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260828/do-we-need-a-close-reason-for-zero-effort-questions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the regex, `\\d+\\.\\d+\\.\\d+\\_(offline|online)`

**Demo:**

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Test strings
        String[] arr = { "EGA_SAMPLE_APP-iOS-master-9.1.1_offline-200710140849862",
                "EGA_SAMPLE_APP-iOS-master-9.2.3_online-200710140849862",
                "EGA_SAMPLE_APP-iOS-master-10.2.3_offline-200710140849862" };
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\d+\\.\\d+\\.\\d+\\_(offline|online)");

        // Print the matching string
        for (String s : arr) {
            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
            while (matcher.find()) {
                System.out.println(matcher.group());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
9.1.1_offline
9.2.3_online
10.2.3_offline
```

**Explanation of the regex:**

1. `\\d+` specifies one or more digits
2. `\\.` specifies a `.`
3. `\\_` specifies a `_`
4. `(offline|online)` specifies `offline` or `online`.

**[Update]**

Based on the edited question i.e. find anything between `EGA_SAMPLE_APP-iOS-master-` and `-An_integer_number`: Use the regex, `EGA_SAMPLE_APP-iOS-master-(.*)-\\d+`

**Demo:**

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Test strings
        String[] arr = { "EGA_SAMPLE_APP-iOS-master-9.1.1_offline-200710140849862",
                "EGA_SAMPLE_APP-iOS-master-9.2.3_online-200710140849862",
                "EGA_SAMPLE_APP-iOS-master-10.2.3_offline-200710140849862",
                "EGA_SAMPLE_APP-iOS-master-anything here-200710140849862" };

        // Define regex pattern
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("EGA_SAMPLE_APP-iOS-master-(.*)-\\d+");

        // Print the matching string
        for (String s : arr) {
            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
            while (matcher.find()) {
                System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
9.1.1_offline
9.2.3_online
10.2.3_offline
anything here
```

**Explanation of the regex:**

`.*` specifies anything and the parenthesis around it specifies a capturing group which I've captured with `group(1)` in the code.

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest the following one line option using `String#replaceAll`:

```
String input = "EGA_SAMPLE_APP-iOS-master-9.2.3_online-200710140849862";
String target = input.replaceAll(".*\\b(\\d+\\.\\d+\\.\\d+_(?:online|offline))\\b.*", "$1");
System.out.println(target);
```

This prints:

```
9.2.3_online
```

Comment: @Toto The thing is, Wiktor is _right_ in that his duplicate link could serve as a good starting point for an answer here.  But, I don't consider the duplicate specific enough to be an exact copy of this question.  Maybe someone will open a discussion on the Meta site about this issue.

Comment: You're right, but I'm not so fluent in English do discuss on Meta ;(

Comment: Also, imho, downvotijg an helpfull answer is never chic. Although a personal choice, I'd always value an answer separate from the question. People have different opinions though. Something covered in multiple threads on meta.